# List image gallery

Tags: html, css, frontend, carousel

dead end for a beginner, building a portfolio website.

The idea is to have categories as a carousel scrollable using the mouse wheel, on choice i can click a category and a vertically scrollable image carousel is going to show projects. Any click on a project is going to show a horizontally scrollable carousel for project details.

No matter what i do it's not going horizontal. Below is my code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #002342
}

h1 {
  color: #0096d1;
  font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6em;
  margin: auto;
}

.Cotainer {
  height: 500px;
  width: 750px;
  background: #E4E4E4;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50px;
}

.Cats li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" , initial-scale=1.0>
    <title>Majd AL HYDER</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Saira+Extra+Condensed:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <H1>My Folio</H1>
    <div class="Cotainer">

      <ul class="Cats">
        <li class="Solid">
          SolidWorks
          <!-list containing projects->
          <-! list containg project details>
            <!-/list containing projects->
        </li>
        <li class="Catia">
          Catia
          <!-list containing projects->
          <-! list containg project details>
            <!-/list containing projects->
        </li>
        <li class="Art">
          Art
          <!-list containing projects->
          <-! list containg project details>
            <!-/list containing projects->
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: You missed one! Add `.Cats { display: flex }` to your CSS. Also, it is common practice to use all lowercase IDs and classnames. I've seen enough case mismatch errors here on SO. Be warned. Furthermore comments are `<!-- .... -->` you have a few errors on those, which can lead to unpredicatable (and unexpected) output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've missed giving the Cats class display: flex is all

```
.Cats {
  display: flex;
}
```

It is needed to make its children display with flex, just like you've already done with

```
.Cats li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  ...
}
```

Good luck with your website

Comment: As I mentioned I my comment. You forgot to comment on the faulty HTML comments `<!-- ... -->`, though.

Comment: thank you guys so much, can't believe this fix, it worked, the new issue is that when i set the single list item to have matching width and height to the white container all "li" items shrink to fit in the white container despite me putting overflow hidden. any one liner fixes !!!? thanks again